# Gail S. Nelson' *A User-Friendly Introduction to Lebesgue Measure and Integration* Confusion about general measure integration

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, borel-sets, borel-measures

In the book that I'm reading (see the title), the author define an integral and its properties on a function having for domain a complete measure space and for codomain the Real line equipped with the Borel sigma-algebra. I wanted to know what is happening to the value of the integral and its properties if I change the sigma algebra of the domain and/or the sigma algebra of the codomain for another random sigma algebra. How does the choice of a sigma-algebra on the domain and/or the codomain influence the integral and its properties? It been 2 days i am searching on the internet and I see nothing on the subject. For example, does the integral of a function having the lebesgue measurable sigma-algebra for the domain equal the integral of the same function if the domain is equipped with the Borel sigma-algebra (since one is the sigma-algebra completion of the other)? (excuse my english, it is not my first language). Also, with what sigma algebra does the lebesgue integral equal the Riemann integral (in my textbook it says borel sigma-algebra at the codomain and borel sigma algebra at the domain but i am not sure if it is the only way possible)

Comment: Even with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra at the codomain and the Borel $\sigma$-algebra at the domain, the Lebesgue integral may exist without the Riemann integral existing. Consider the domain $[0,1]$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra, the codomain $\Bbb R$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and the indicator function $1_{[0,1] \cap \Bbb Q}$.  This function is  Lebesgue integrable and $\int 1_{[0,1] \cap \Bbb Q}=0$. However, it is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: You asked: How does the choice of a $\sigma$-algebra on the domain and/or the codomain influence the integral and its properties?  Changing those choices changes which functions are measurable (and so integrable). Moreover, the choice of  a $\sigma$-algebra on the domain is associate to the choice of measure in the domain, which impacts the value of the integral.  Of course, the general (abstract) properties of the integral remain the same.

Comment: so integrating with lebesgue measurable sigma algebra witll give a different result than integrating with Borel sigma algebra? Or since Lebesgue measurable is the completion of Borel it will give the same result?

Comment: Using Lebesgue sigma-algebra in the domain will make more functions to be measurable than using Borel sigma-algebra in the domain. So, for instance, there ares functions $f$ that are measurable if we use  Lebesgue sigma-algebra in the domain and have $\int f =0$, but $f$ is not measurable if we use  Borel sigma-algebra in the domain, and so $\int f$ is not defined.

Comment: @Ramiro for the case that the function is measurable with both borel and lebesgue sigma algebra at the domain, will the integral value be the same?

Comment: If the measure is the Lebesgue measure in both case, the answer is yes.